# How to start ropemacs-mode automatically?

Tags: python, emacs, rope

When I open a python file I have to manually start ropemacs-mode to get the key bindings each time. I tried adding something like this to automatically start ropemacs:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
                               (ropemacs-mode)
                               ))
```

But it seems to break flymake. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No need for a lambda; just use 'ropemacs-mode.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use ropemacs but the [readme](https://bitbucket.org/agr/ropemacs/raw/7af544334b85/README.txt) says like this

After installing pymacs, add these lines to your `~/.emacs` file::

  `(require 'pymacs)

  (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")`

Comment: I have that in my init.el. I can access all the ropemacs functions by typing out M-x rope-*, but the minor mode is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with some code for using autocomplete.el along with ropemacs and yas which I found here:

http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/

Once I commented out the block relating to autocomplete everything else started working as expected.